# Tkinter input for pyplot graph

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I am very new to Python(coming from C/C++) and I have some trouble getting this little program to work.

It will get some market date from yahoo and print out two graphs. The graphs were working at first and then I added the tkinter input window. Just press "submit" and "print". The problem is that the graphs are not plotted, I assume it has sth to do with the tkinter not finishing or that it cannot open a second window anymore, any help would be highly appreciated

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from itertools import accumulate
from tkinter import *
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

#Functions
def VWAP(data):
return(np.cumsum(data.Bought*data.Close)/
np.cumsum(data.Bought)).round(2)

def Print():
df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo',  conversion.start_date, conversion.end_date)
df2['30_SMA_Close']  = pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(df2['Close'], 30)
df2['150_SMA_Close'] = pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(df2['Close'], 150)
df2["Bought"] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,1000,len(df2.index)), index=df2.index)
df2["vwap"] = pd.Series(VWAP(df2), index=df2.index)
#print("VWAP : ", df2["vwap"])

print("----------------PLOT-----------------")   
top = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=6)
top.plot(df2.index, df2["Close"], label='Close')
top.plot(df2.index, df2['30_SMA_Close'], label='30 Day SMA')
top.plot(df2.index, df2['150_SMA_Close'], label='150 Day SMA')
top.plot(df2.index, df2['vwap'], label='VWAP',color='k',linestyle="--")
plt.title('S&P Price from 2007 - 2012')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints = 1, prop={'size':7})
bottom = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (4,0), rowspan=2, colspan=6)
bottom.bar(df2.index, df2['Volume'])
plt.title('S&P Trading Volume in Millions')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,8)
print("----------------PLOT END-----------------")


def conversion():
print("Data conversion")
conversion.moniker = e1.get()
conversion.start_date =   datetime.datetime.strptime(e2.get(),'%Y-%m-%d')
conversion.end_date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(e3.get(),'%Y-%m-%d')


master = Tk()

Label(master, text="Moniker Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Start Date").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="End Date").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.insert(10,"SPY")
e2 = Entry(master)
e2.insert(10,"2010-12-31")
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.insert(10,"2014-01-01")

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
def close_window (): master.destroy()

Button(master, text='Cancel', command=close_window).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Submit', command=conversion).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Print', command=Print).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

 #df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo', conversion.start_date, conversion.end_date)
#df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo',datetime.datetime(2010,1,1),datetime.datetime(2014,1,1) )
#mainloop( )
master.destroy()
```

Comment: Indentions are incorrect - use button `{}` during question edition.

Comment: Is `close_window()` empty function ? Then use `pass` in it.

Comment: You run `master.destroy()` in last line so you close window. And you forgot to use root.masterloop()

Comment: missed the master.destroy()

Comment: Paste your working code again (and use on it button `{}`)

Comment: Did you run code in console/cmd.exe ? Maybe there are some error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run all code because I don't have some modules
but if I press `submit` and then `print` I got some graph.
I changed almost nothing.

---

EDIT: I found problem - you need `plt.show()` before `print('PLOT END')`

---

Here my code with mods

- button `Print` calls `conversion` so I don't need button `Submit`
- dates in plot title.

.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import numpy as np
import datetime
#import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
#from itertools import accumulate
from tkinter import *
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

#Functions
def VWAP(data):
    return(np.cumsum(data.Bought*data.Close)/
    np.cumsum(data.Bought)).round(2)

def ploting():
    conversion()
    df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo',  conversion.start_date, conversion.end_date)
    df2['30_SMA_Close']  = pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(df2['Close'], 30)
    df2['150_SMA_Close'] = pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(df2['Close'], 150)
    df2["Bought"] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,1000,len(df2.index)), index=df2.index)
    df2["vwap"] = pd.Series(VWAP(df2), index=df2.index)
    #print("VWAP : ", df2["vwap"])

    print("----------------PLOT-----------------")   
    top = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=6)

    print top.plot(df2.index, df2["Close"], label='Close')
    print top.plot(df2.index, df2['30_SMA_Close'], label='30 Day SMA')
    print top.plot(df2.index, df2['150_SMA_Close'], label='150 Day SMA')
    print top.plot(df2.index, df2['vwap'], label='VWAP',color='k',linestyle="--")
    print plt.title('S&P Price from %s - %s' % (e2.get(), e3.get()))
    print plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints = 1, prop={'size':7})
    bottom = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (4,0), rowspan=2, colspan=6)
    print bottom.bar(df2.index, df2['Volume'])
    print plt.title('S&P Trading Volume in Millions')
    print plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,8)
    print plt.show() # <---- HERE
    print("----------------PLOT END-----------------")


def conversion():
    print("Data conversion")
    conversion.moniker = e1.get()
    conversion.start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(e2.get(),'%Y-%m-%d')
    conversion.end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(e3.get(),'%Y-%m-%d')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def close_window (): 
     master.destroy()

master = Tk()

Label(master, text="Moniker Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Start Date").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="End Date").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.insert(10,"SPY")
e2 = Entry(master)
e2.insert(10,"2010-12-31")
e3 = Entry(master)
e3.insert(10,"2014-01-01")

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(master, text='Cancel', command=close_window).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
#Button(master, text='Submit', command=conversion).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Plot', command=ploting).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

#df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo', conversion.start_date, conversion.end_date)
#df2 = web.DataReader(conversion.moniker, 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(2010,1,1),datetime.datetime(2014,1,1) )

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

2008-12-31 - 2013-01-01

[image]

1998-12-31 - 2004-01-01

[image]

Comment: That is what it should look like, have you tried a different time range as well, so that the graph changes

Comment: See new images `2008-12-31 - 2013-01-01` and `1998-12-31 - 2004-01-01`

Comment: I was running code in some Python Shell (`DreamingPie`) and I got plots. But it didn't work when I run it directly in console. But I found problem. You need `plt.show()` before `print("PLOT END")`. I add my code with answer.

Comment: Hi so I tried running it on my machine again and I get a syntax error on line 27

print top.plot(df2.index, df2["Close"], label='Close')

any idea what I am missing ??? cheers

Comment: Solved: Missing brackets around all the print statements